# Why is my shower dripping in these situations?

Tags: shower

Why is the stall shower dripping when

1. the hot water (not cold) water bathroom faucet is turned on, or
2. the bathtub in the adjacent bathroom is turned on

Comment: Would guess water movement, juggles the dipping pipe slightly and excess water in the shower-head comes out. See if it happens with the dripping shower-head removed - or - repeatedly test it and see if the drip dries up after doing this repeatedly. If there was an actual leak, would expect a constant drip, unless the shower is right at the point of failure, and the slight pressure changes causes the leak

Comment: Is this a continuous drip for the entire time the other water source is on or is it a few drops then stops?

Answer (score 1):

Washer less faucets use water pressure to block the water. Sounds crazy but the pressure on the O rings is part of how water is stopped when the pressure is reduced some faucets will even turn on. searching this site you may find that question in that case adding more spring pressure on the oring plate was the fix of i remember correctly. Low pressure is the reason.